# Read Location from SIM868 while using as PPP(Modem Mode) on Raspberry

Tags: python, raspbian, ppp

I trying to get device location using linked [sim868](https://www.m2mmarket.com.tr/gsm/gprs/gnss/bluetooth-hat-for-raspberry-pi-with-sim868) shield on Raspberry 3A+.

1. State: I have got successfully get device location with AT+ commands via UART protocol using Python.
2. State: I have got successfully to use sim868 as a modem (PPP mode)([SIM868 PPP Dail-up Networking](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM868_PPP_Dail-up_Networking))

The problem is that when I want to use Sim868 as a model I cant send AT+ command to get location values because of one UART port can not be use same time.

- Raspberry system using the UART in the second state.
- I am using the same UART in the first state.

Is there any way to get location data from sim868 even if it is using
PPP mode?

If there is please explain how do I get these locations?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get location data from the SIM868 while it is being used as a modem in PPP mode, you can try the following steps:

1. use a software-based serial port:
   As you mentioned, one UART port cannot be used for both PPP communication and AT commands at the same time. However, you can create a software-based serial port on the Raspberry Pi and use it to send AT commands to the SIM868 while it is being used as a PPP modem. A great Python library to do this is PySerial.
2. disable the echo on SIM868
   If you still encounter problems, you can try disabling the echo on the SIM868 to reduce the chance of receiving redundant data.
3. send AT commands to SIM868
   Once you have a software-based serial port set up and access to the SIM868, you can send AT commands to the SIM868 over the software-based serial port and get the location data.

Here is a sample code that might be helpful:

```
import serial

# set up software-based serial port for SIM868
sim_serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)

# disable echo on SIM868
sim_serial.write("ATE0\r\n")

# send AT command for location info
sim_serial.write("AT+CGNSINF\r\n")
location_data = sim_serial.readline()

# parse location data and do something with it
```

Please note that this solution is not guaranteed to work for every setup, so some adjustments may be needed based on your specific hardware and software configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using /dev/ttyS0 port for two states. Is there any other uart in SIM868 to connect for another serial? I thing it doesn`t matter software-serial if there is no any other uart in SIM868.

Comment: ```serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/serial0: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/serial0'``` is what I got